# Is there a way to finish all other activities upon arrival of my MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Every time MainActivity is accessed, I need it to be the only activity that's still alive - as in the only one that hasn't been `finish()ed` basically.

I know about the solution of every time I access the MainActivity I add the flag for `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`. This is fine, as long as the user doesn't access the main activity by pressing the back button. So my `onPause()` functions in most of my activities contain `finish()` as well.

My main issue with this is that it is a lot of code that seems a little unintuitive and repetitive, as well as having to sacrifice any state say ActivityB might have been in going to ActivityC; like if the program flow was as follows:

```
MainActivity   <--->   ActivityB   <--->   ActivityC
```

What I want to know is if there is a way that I can end every running activity apart from the one that is visible, in the `onResume()` method of my MainActivity. This would ensure MainActivity is always the only activity that is alive when it is accessed, as well as Activity B and C being able to retain their states when they are navigated between each other.

Comment: try `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: cheers, I'll give it a go